# comando que muestre todos los archivos y directorios del directorio /bin

Tags: linux

Buen dia compañeros estoy tratando se sacar un comando comando que muestre todos los archivos y directorios del directorio /bin.

Comment: ¿Te refieres mostrar también los archivos y carpetas que están dentro de las carpetas de la carpeta bin? Osea de manera recursiva.

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentado para resolver tu problema? ¿Ya haz buscado preguntas semejantes en el sitio? Me parece que podría haber muchas que te podrían ayudar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Comandos:

Para mostrar todos los directorios y archivos de manera recursiva:

```
ls -R
```

Para mostrar todos los directorios y archivos ocultos de manera recursiva:

```
ls -aR
```

Para mostrar directorios y archivos ocultos:

```
ls -a
```